# SUMIF with multiple match criteria in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a formula so that if in cell `E2` it says "Market", "Limit", or "Stop" it adds the numbers in cells `L2` and `M2`.

```
=SUMIF(E2, "Market" "Limit" "Stop", L2+M2)
```

These expressions are part of a data validation list, I'm not sure if that effects the result or not. I've tried the help files, Google searches and formula wizard. I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If looks like you are applying `SUMIF` where an `IF` might work as from the references in your example they are all on a single row. As such you could use:

```
=IF(OR(E2="Market",E2="Limit",E2="Stop"),L2+M2,0)
```

This combines the `IF` statement with the `OR` statement so that we can make multiple comparisons.

addendum:

```
=IF(OR(E2="Market",E2="Limit",E2="Stop"),L2+M2,IF(E2="Sell",M2,0))
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a logical error in my sheet, though (not your formula), do you know how I can expand on this to make it include that if it says "sell" in E2 it just displays the value of M2?

Comment: @Alex Just make another `IF` in the else part of the formula. You should know the syntax now.